# React Native FlatList extraData not rerendering

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am not able to re-render my FlatList component. I have tried everything that I can think of. I have tried updating a boolean value for extraData with this.setState, I have passed Immutable.Map to extraData. But nothing seems to work although I know my component has updated correctly and everything is in place when component re-render, but FlatList does not re-render although I have passed changed data to extraData. I just cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is my component without imports and styles:

```
class DetailsScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const {
      data: { list, letterIndexes, alphabet },
      savedList
    } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
    this.state = {
      alphabet,
      letter: "A",
      letterIndexes,
      letterIndexesValues: Object.values(letterIndexes),
      savedList: savedList || [],
      list,
      updated: false
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { list, savedList, refreshFlatList, updated } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      list: this.updateListActiveState(list, savedList),
      updated: !updated
    });
  }

  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
    title: `${navigation.state.params.title}`
  });

  /**
   * Adds active prop to each object in array.
   * If they exists in savedList then we set active prop as true
   *
   * @param {Array<Object>} list - Names list
   * @param {Array<Object>} savedList - Saved names list
   * @returns {Array<Object>} list
   */
  updateListActiveState(list, savedList) {
    return list.map(item => {
      item.active = savedList.some(s => item.name === s.name);
      return item;
    });
  }

  /**
   * Updates list names state with new state
   */
  onClick = savedList => {
    const { list, updated } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      list: this.updateListActiveState(list, savedList),
      updated: !updated
    });
  };

  /**
   * Renders FlatList single item
   */
  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return <NameItem key={item.id} item={item} onClick={this.onClick} />;
  };

  onLetterPress(letter) {
    const { letterIndexes } = this.state;

    this.setState({ letter });

    try {
      this.flatListRef.scrollToIndex({
        animated: true,
        index: letterIndexes[letter]
      });
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  getItemLayout = (data, index) => {
    return { length: ROW_HEIGHT, offset: ROW_HEIGHT * index, index };
  };

  handleScroll = event => {
    const { letterIndexes, letterIndexesValues } = this.state;
    const y = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y + ROW_HEIGHT;
    const index = parseInt(y / ROW_HEIGHT);

    let letter = "A";
    let cnt = 0;

    for (const key in letterIndexes) {
      if (letterIndexes.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const startIndex = letterIndexes[key];
        const endIndex =
          letterIndexesValues[cnt + 1] !== undefined
            ? letterIndexesValues[cnt + 1]
            : startIndex;

        if (startIndex <= index && index <= endIndex) {
          letter = key;
          break;
        }
      }

      cnt += 1;
    }

    if (letter !== this.state.letter) {
      this.setState({ letter });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { list, letterIndexes, alphabet, savedList, updated } = this.state;
    const {
      alphabetContainer,
      container,
      letter,
      letterActive,
      letterLast
    } = styles;
    console.log(updated);
    return (
      <View className={container}>
        <FlatList
          data={list}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
          initialNumToRender={20}
          onScrollEndDrag={this.handleScroll}
          extraData={updated}
          ref={ref => {
            this.flatListRef = ref;
          }}
        />
        <ScrollView
          style={alphabetContainer}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        >
          <View>
            {alphabet.map((l, i) => {
              const active = l === this.state.letter ? letterActive : "";
              const last = i === alphabet.length - 1 ? letterLast : "";

              return (
                <Text
                  key={i}
                  style={[letter, active, last]}
                  onPress={() => this.onLetterPress(l)}
                >
                  {l}
                </Text>
              );
            })}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Same here. I also tried using key for the flatlist and the parent but nothing. Did you managed to solve it?